# Convert Word to PDF in c# with free libs

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I know that exist some post about this issue but never cover my simple problem. I need to print my DOCX or XLXS to PDF. First of all DOCX.

I don't want to use word Interop because this required word on server machine.

I try to use PDFCreator but I can't pass my docx to PDFCreator... or I'm not able to do this.

UPDATE

Using free libs and without word interop

Comment: What's the question? Asking us to recommend a library is off topic, posts with no effort or code are also off topic, FYI.

Comment: The question is: is possibile to do that with PDFCreator or other free libs?

Comment: Check if this helps: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Manage-Word-documents-in-C-77b23282

Comment: You can try this [method](https://codewin.org/convert-word-to-pdf-using-c-program/)

Answer (score 0):

I used NuGet to install something called freeSpire.Doc which claims to convert the first 500 paragraphs for free.  Seems to working so far.

Answer (score -1):

File -> Export -> Create PDF/XPS-document

Comment: Thunder_Lord79 i need to do this via con in c#

Comment: This sounds very much as a off-topic question.